# Domain of Integral $\int_{5}^{x} \frac {dt}{(1-t^2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

A function reads 
$$ F(x) = \int_{5}^{x} \frac {dt}{(1-t^2)} $$

Barrons says that the domain of F must be that $x >1$. But why can't $x$ be less than $1$ as well? As long as $x$ does not equal $1$, why is there a problem?

Comment: The integrand is undefined at both 1 and -1. If $x<1$ the resulting integral will be improper. You need to check if the integral converges in that case (you can use partial fractions, for instance, to do the necessary analysis).

Answer (score 2):

Because the integral
$$ \int_{5}^{1} \frac {dt}{1-t^2} $$
is not convergent. Doing partial fractions
$$
\frac {1}{1-t^2}=\frac12\Bigl(\frac {1}{1-t}+\frac {1}{1+t}\Bigr),
$$
and
$$
\lim_{a\to1^+}\int_5^a\frac {dt}{1-t}=\lim_{a\to1^+}\log(t-1)\,\Bigr|_5^a=\lim_{a\to1^+}(\log(a-1)-\log4)=-\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $\int_{5}^{x} \frac {dt}{(1-t^2)}$ to exist as a Riemann integrale , the function $f(t)=\frac 1 {(1-t^2)} $ must be correctly defined on $[5, x]$ interval. If we take $x \le 1$, then $1 \in [5, x]$ and the function $f$ is not correctly defined in $t=1$